# Disappearing import statement in Android code

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using "Hello, Android" 1.5& 1.6 with the 2.1 android Java build. I typed:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
```

It disappeared as soon as I finished typing!!  Help, please.?

Comment: Where are you typing it?

Comment: There's no Android 2.1 yet... you probably mean 2.0.1?

Comment: Eclipse has a setting to remove unused imports when you save a file.  Is it possible that you have this feature enabled?

Comment: If you have the automatically-resolve-imports option enabled in Eclipse, it may well be automatically removing unused imports when you save the file.  Don't type imports manually, just write your code and hit Ctrl+Shift+O to let Eclipse figure it out magically! ;)

Answer (score 3):

By default Eclipse hides all `import` statements under a single line.

Click the `+` button next to the `import` you can see and it should show them all.

Answer (score 1):

**Settings** -> **Editor** -> **General** -> **Auto Import**.

You will find two options.

**1. Add unambiguous imports on the fly**.

**2. Optimize imports on the fly**.

When we type any class or annotation name and if the class is unambiguous and it is still not imported then **IDE will automatically add the imports for us if** **Add unambiguous imports on the fly is selected**. If the imports are ambiguous then IDE prompts us which class/interface need to add for import statement.

If "**Optimize imports on the fly**" option is turned on, when you import something then IDE will check whether it is used in the code or not. **If the answer is "No" then IDE optimizes the imports and removes it. For solving this issue** **uncheck the "Optimize imports on the fly "option**.

To learn more check the below links,

[Remove unused imports in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273434/remove-unused-imports-in-android-studio)

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206223159-Java-import-hiding-disappearing