# Remove unused imports in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I recently started Android Studio IDE to make my android apps. I find shortkey to remove unused import in Android Studio is not working (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>)

What is shortcut key to do same in Android Studio?

Comment: If you don't want to learn new shortcuts you can also set AS to use Eclipse shortcuts: http://mussharapp.blogspot.de/2013/07/android-studio-keyboard-shortcut.html

Comment: On Mac, `Ctrl + Alt + o`

Comment: File > Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import - Optimize imports on the fly

Answer (score 516, accepted):

Simple, right click on your project in Android Studio, then click on the **Optimize Imports** that should work.

[image: screenshot]

### Update

To do same thing which I described above, you can do same just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, it will optimize imports of your current file and your entire project depends on your selection in a dialog.

[image]

Comment: Also note for Mac users, the command is still *Control*, not *Command*.

Comment: For Android Studio Build 141, Ctrl+Alt+O only optimizes for the current file. In order to optimize your entire project, you will have to follow the right+click method stated above.

Answer (score 181):

You can do it on the fly. You don't need to call (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) or "Project/Optimize Imports..." each time.

Just set this checkbox in `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Auto Import` -> `Optimize Imports on the fly`.

[image]

On OSX: `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Auto Import` -> `Optimize imports on the fly`

Comment: Worth noting that there options for ”Optimize imports on the fly” and “Add unambiguous imports on the fly” for the Kotlin language (in addition to Java) in Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 (which, in my case, was the language I wanted to modify settings for).

Answer (score 39):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

A dialog box will appear with a few options.  You can choose to have the dialog box not appear again in the future if you wish, setting a default behavior.

[image]

Comment: Also note for Mac users, the command is still *Control*, not *Command*.

Comment: ... In resume, the Mac users will press *fn* + *control* + *option* + *O*.

Comment: @FilipedeLimaBrito, as a Mac user, when I press _fn + control + option + O_, I get the dialog "Choose a method to override/implement", so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Well... I pressed this combination using the Android Studio version 2.0 and worked for me. The *control* + *option* + *O* key worked too (I noticed right now), so, forget my last comment and try this combination.

Comment: And, before any question, I wrote those comments because I was a slightly confused about what was the combination to use the *Alt* key on Mac Computers.

Answer (score 30):

It is very Simple Just Follow the below step.

1. Switch your project in Project Mode.

[image]

2. Then right-click on project name.
3. The final step is to select the **Optimize imports** from popup menu.

Enjoy!!

Comment: That's worked for me to optimize import the entire project

Answer (score 10):

On Mac use `control + option + O`

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> works pretty well and removes unused imports

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for the late answer.. For mac users  <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>
Try this.. It is working for me..

Comment: Someone already posted this 1,5 years ago. Look before you answer

Comment: It's `control` + `option` + `o`. I tried this in Macbook Pro M1 2020.

Comment: For poor devs, still working on old MBP 2015. Command option o.

Answer (score 5):

here Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
windows 10

```
 ctrl+alt+o
```

worked perfectly

[image]

Answer (score 4):

there is also an Android Studio (1.4) setting to optimze imports on the fly: see Settings->Editor->General->Auto Import.

Answer (score 2):

I think Ctrl + Alt + O works when the import is unused but a valid import. However, say you try to import a class from a package that does not exist or no longer exists (which can happen during refactoring), the shortcut command does not work (atleast it didn't for me). If you have more than one file like this, things can get problematic.

To solve this problem, click on Analyse -> Inspect code -> (select your module / project). Let it perform the analysis. Go down to Imports  -> Unused imports. Click on the "Delete unnecessary import" button that appears on the right.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for **Flutter** Just set this checkbox `Settings` -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Flutter` -> `Organize imports on save`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> with the cursor on top of the import. The Optimize imports menu will show. Press Enter again. Your unused imports will be removed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since Android Studio 3+, this can be done by open the option  "Optimize imports".

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> the select "Optimize imports".

[image]

This must be enough to removed the unused imports.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS (Monterey) + Android Studio (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1):
To Remove unused imports, follow below procedures.

Android Studio -> Code -> Optimize Imports

Shortcut key: Option + Command + O

Please see screenshot for more clarification. Thanks.

[image: android studio screenshot on mac]

Answer (score 0):

On Linux : hover the mouse over the imports, then  `Alt+Shift+Enter`

Answer (score -1):

you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Android Studio as Shortcut Key

Comment: No, that does not remove unused imports. It's used to suggest missing imports

Comment: this is not an answer to the question asked