# Remove unused import in Reformat Code in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I know `Ctrl+Shift+O` shortcut key for remove unused import but is possible to remove unused import in reformat code in android studio.

Edit 1:

What i am looking for : A option for remove unused import when reformat code.reformat code option usually find in `Preferences->Editor->Code Style->Java`

Comment: you can format your code using Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I know but with default configuration format code not removed unused import

Comment: So what is the problem. You need both the thing with one shortcut key?

Comment: @AndyDeveloper yes . in `phpstorm` you can use some thing like this and i guess this place would have

Comment: You can change the keyboard shortcut. Goto Preferences->KeyMap-> here you search for reformat code and unused import you can set the both with same shortcut key. Well I am not sure whether it is working or not because as for I know it will not allow to set both the operation using one shortcut key but you can try it out.

Comment: To do it on the fly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36079543/4624156

Comment: @JoshLaird Thanks but I'm looking for integrate reformat and remove unused import not shortcut key

Comment: ctrl+alt+l to reformat the code

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Open reformat file dialog (`ctrl+shift+alt+L`), there is an option there "Optimize import", select it and press `run`. Now whenever you reformat code (`ctrl+alt+L`) it will also optimize imports.

Comment: `cmd + option + shift + L` for Mac users.

Comment: control + option + o for mac users

Answer (score 9):

In android studio `Ctrl+Shift+O` does not remove unused imports it is used in Eclipse, here we can use `Ctrl+Alt+O` to remove unused imports and `Ctrl+Alt+l` to format code.

Comment: My question is about integrate reformat and remove unused import was not about shortcut key.I change this shortcut key and may be different with the default settings

Answer (score 3):

The "Optimize imports" option is in the "Reformat File Dialog".
You could find the shortcuts in Preferences->Keymap with key word "Show Reformat File Dialog"

Comment: `Code -> "Show Reformat File Dialog` on Mac Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

For Mac use **⌃** + **⌥** + **O**
For Windows use **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **O**

Chill Pill :)

Comment: Thanks, still workin in Arctic Fox on mac big sur: For Mac use ⌃ + ⌥ + O