# Add lib or module return 'unused import statement'

Tags: android, android-studio

Why does import error(unused import statement) appear when I add Library or Module by Project Structure?

It's the same for Clean or Rebuild project.

What's the problem?

For example, in Project1, 'unused import statement' is no problem. But

Project2 occurs at 'unused import statement'

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in settings.gradle like that..

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I entered the place where you said it and set up 'include'. But 'unused import statement' is still up.

Comment: Please check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273434/remove-unused-imports-in-android-studio